# Why does ActiveModel::Attributes.attribute cause permitted strong parameters to disappear in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters, activemodel

I have a form model:

```rb
class Foo
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes

  attribute :bar, :string

  attr_reader :bazes
end
```

And a controller:

```rb
class FoosController < ApplicationController
  def create
    render html: foo_params.inspect
  end

  private

  def foo_params
    params.require(:foo).permit(:bar, bazes: [])
  end
end
```

When I use `attribute :bar, :string`, my parameters are such that `bazes` are not permitted (`nil`).  When it's replaced by `attr_accessor :bar`, it works as I expect.  I'm at a loss for why.  (Please note, the above code is just an illustration.  It **doesn't replicate the behavior**, but I'm certain that changing `attribute` to `attr_accessor` is enough to trigger the problem in my code.)

Details: this is on Rails version 6.0.3.7.  I'm testing using Rswag.

Comment: The above code does not make sense because the controller does not even use the model you posted. Is there something missing?

Comment: Your model attributes have nothing to do with parameter whitelisting. ActionController::Parameters does not know or care about your model. Its just a hash like object whith a `permitted` attribute and some fancy slicing methods. This code does not  reproduce the bug your are mentioning and you're most likely chasing a red herring. Can you show us the test?

Comment: I agree that it doesn't make sense, but I _have_ narrowed it down to the call to `attribute`.  Adding _any_ calls to `attribute` is enough to trigger the unexpected behavior.  Given this, I'm not certain about strong parameters being "just a hash like object" (though I thought that as well).  Consider that there are also classes like `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`.  I'll look into sharing more code, but I can't share it all verbatim.